# How to determine the spectrum of the following operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ a Hilbert space and $f \in H^{'}$. Fixed $z \in H$, $z \neq 0$, define $T: H \rightarrow H$ by $T(x) = f(x)z$. Then $T$ is a compact non-self-adjoint operator.
How to determine the spectrum of  $ T $?

I verified that $|| T || = || f |||| z || $ and I'm trying to verify that $ \sigma (T) = \{\lambda: | \lambda  | \leq || f |||| z || \} $, I have no idea how to make the inclusion $ \sigma (T) \supset \{ \lambda: | \lambda  | \leq || f |||| z || \} $. In fact, is it not necessary to place any restrictions on the $ f $ for the result to be true? Or does it work in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  is compact its spectrum consists of eigenvalues, in addition to zero, which is always in the spectrum. To find the nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda$, write
$$
f(x)z=\lambda x,
$$
which implies that the eigenvector $x$ is a multiple of $z$, and hence can be taken to be $z$ itself, since eigenvalues are scalable.  The eigenvalue in turn is computed by solving the equation
$$
f(z)z=\lambda z,
$$
whose solution is clearly $\lambda=f(z)$.  In other words,
$$\sigma(T)=\{0,f(z)\}.$$